# Operating the buttons on the nodes according to certain conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a classic button on each of my nodes. I want them to take action according to the node they are on when clicked, but I couldn't find how to do it.

I have 4 database tables Material/Brand/Serie/Product. For example, when DeleteButton_Click runs, if the node it is on is the Brand node, how do I make it work accordingly?

```
                            <Button Width="18" Height="20" Click="DeleteButton_Click" Margin="2 0 0 0" Tag="{Binding DataContext}">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Sil" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
```

TreeNodeViewModel Code.

```
namespace Bornander.UI.ViewModels
```

{
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
public static void AddRange(this ObservableCollection collection, IEnumerable items)
{
foreach (var item in items)
{
collection.Add(item);
}
}
}

```
public class TreeNodeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeNodeViewModel> children;
    private readonly string name;
    private static int nextId = 1;

    public int Id { get; }
    private bool expanded;
    private bool match = true;
    private bool isLastChild;
    private bool isSelected;
    private object item;

    public TreeNodeViewModel(string name, IEnumerable<TreeNodeViewModel> children)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNodeViewModel>();
        this.children.AddRange(children);
        Id = nextId++;
    }

    public TreeNodeViewModel(string name)
        : this(name, Enumerable.Empty<TreeNodeViewModel>())
    {
    }

    public void AddChildren(ObservableCollection<TreeNodeViewModel> children)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            this.children.Add(child);
            child.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public void AddChildren(params TreeNodeViewModel[] children)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            this.children.Add(child);
            child.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    private bool IsCriteriaMatched(string criteria)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria) || name.Contains(criteria);
    }

    private void CheckChildren(string criteria, TreeNodeViewModel parent)
    {
        foreach (var child in parent.Children)
        {
            if (child.IsLeaf && !child.IsCriteriaMatched(criteria))
            {
                child.IsMatch = false;
            }
            CheckChildren(criteria, child);
        }
    }

    public void ApplyCriteria(string criteria, Stack<TreeNodeViewModel> ancestors)
    {
        if (IsCriteriaMatched(criteria))
        {
            IsMatch = true;
            foreach (var ancestor in ancestors)
            {
                ancestor.IsMatch = true;
                ancestor.IsExpanded = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria);
                CheckChildren(criteria, ancestor);
            }
            IsExpanded = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsMatch = false;
        }

        ancestors.Push(this);
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.ApplyCriteria(criteria, ancestors);
        }
        ancestors.Pop();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TreeNodeViewModel> Children => children;

    public string Name => name;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get => expanded;
        set
        {
            if (value == expanded)
            {
                return;
            }

            expanded = value;
            if (expanded)
            {
                foreach (var child in Children)
                {
                    child.IsMatch = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsMatch
    {
        get => match;
        set
        {
            if (value == match)
            {
                return;
            }

            match = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsMatch));
        }
    }

    public bool IsLastChild
    {
        get => isLastChild;
        set
        {
            if (value == isLastChild)
            {
                return;
            }

            isLastChild = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsLastChild));
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => isSelected;
        set
        {
            if (value == isSelected)
            {
                return;
            }

            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
        }
    }

    public object Item
    {
        get => item;
        set
        {
            if (value == item)
            {
                return;
            }

            item = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Item));
        }
    }

    public bool IsLeaf => !Children.Any();

    public TreeNodeViewModel Parent { get; private set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Still i cant find any solve.

Comment: Little tough to exactly nail down what you are going for, but I will make a few guesses. You will want to utilize `DataTemplate`'s for your "Nodes". This way you can select the corresponding UI with a `DataTemplateSelector` based on the incoming Data Type. Then we will want to utilize `Command`'s so you can bind the Actions to the now corresponding ViewModel, instead of relying on the Events of the Code Behind. Google "RelayCommand WPF" for some examples.